# Entity removed from cache despite error on DELETE

Tags: angular, ngrx, angular8, ngrx-entity, angular-ngrx-data

I am using Angular 8 with `@ngrx/data` to manage my entities. When I initiate a delete operation which fails (server returns 500), the entity is removed from the ngrx client side cache, despite it not being deleted on the server.

How do I prevent the entity from being removed from the cache on error? Or how do I re-add the (non-)deleted entity back to the cache on error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use pesimistic save https://ngrx.io/guide/data/entity-change-tracker#save-errors

> The EntityActions whose operation names end in _OPTIMISTIC start an
>   optimistic save.
>
> Many apps are easier to build when saves are "optimistic" because the
>   changes are immediately available to application code that is watching
>   collection selectors. The app doesn't have to wait for confirmation
>   that the entity operation succeeded on the server.
>
> A pessimistic save doesn't update the store until the server until the
>   server confirms that the save succeeded, which NgRx Data then turns
>   into a "SUCCESS" action that updates the collection. With a
>   pessimistic save, the changes won't be available in the store

Comment: Thanks, it took me a while to figure out exactly how to do it, but that's the solution. Thanks. For those interested, the entity service `delete` method accepts a 2nd options argument which includes the optimistic/pessimistic flag.

Comment: for those coming later, the relevent overload looks like this:
`delete(key: number | string, options?: EntityActionOptions)` and options looks like this: https://ngrx.io/api/data/EntityActionOptions